# Can we get People Talking About This for a post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, statistics, facebook-page, facebook-insights

Is there a way to get the "People Talking About This" statistic for a **specific post** on a Facebook Page ? The Insights API doesn't say it's possible. ( post_storytellers doesn't exist )

Answer (score 0):

'People Talking About This' aggregates various interactions into a single metric including:

- liking a Page
- posting to a Page’s Wall
- liking, commenting on or sharing a Page post (or other content on a page, like photos, videos or albums)
- answering a Question posted
- RSVPing to an event
- mentioning a Page in a post
- phototagging a Page
- liking or sharing a check-in deal
- or checking in at a Place.

As far as i'm aware there's no way to retrieve this value using the graph api without scraping the page directly.

You can however retrieve the total_count for a url which is an aggregation of shares, likes, comments via FQL, for example: [https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='https://www.stackoverflow.com'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat)

more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat